# Delphi não escreve em arquivo txt

Tags: delphi

O código abaixo cria o arquivo txt mas não escreve nele. O que pode ser?

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
arq: TextFile;
begin
qr.Active:= true;
qr.First;
  try
    AssignFile(arq, 'd:\\tabuada.txt');
    Rewrite(arq);
    writeln(arq, 'teste');
    while not qr.Eof do
      begin
      writeln(arq, qr.FieldValues['ine'] + ';' + qr.FieldValues['cmp'] + ';' + qr.FieldValues['cbo'] + ';' + qr.FieldValues['pa'] + ';' + qr.FieldValues['idade'] + ';' + '1;' + qr.FieldValues['quant'] + ';' + qr.FieldValues['profissional'] + ';' + qr.FieldValues['cnesdescricao'] + ';' + qr.FieldValues['cbodescricao'] + ';' + qr.FieldValues['padescricao']);
      qr.Next;
      end;

    CloseFile(arq);
    ShowMessage('ok2');
  except
  end;
end;
```

Não apresenta erro e nem mostra a mensagem 'ok2'

Comment: O fato de não mostrar erro é devido você ter um `Try..Except` sem o tratamento devido. Ponha um `ShowMessage` no Except com o `on E.Exception do` com a mensagem do erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evite criar try-excepts vazios. A informação do problema provavelmente vai aparecer se alterar o **except** para:

```
except
  on E: Exception do
    ShowMessage(E.Message);
end;
```

Quanto ao problema, é possível que você não tenha permissão para criar um arquivo neste diretório **D:**, o que seria resolvido rodando o executável como administrador, ou salvando em outra pasta que não seja a raíz. Mas isso só pode ser dito com certeza através do código no except.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de alterar o arquivo verifique se ele existe ou não logo depois do `AssignFile()`, fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
if FileExists('d:\\tabuada.txt') then
   Append(arq)
else
   Rewrite(arq);
```

No lugar `qr.FieldValues` substitua por `qr.FieldByName()`, respeitando o tipo dos campos do banco.

```
Varchar: qr.FieldByName('NOME_CAMPO').AsString;
Integer: qr.FieldByName('NOME_CAMPO').AsInteger;
Numeric: qr.FieldByName('NOME_CAMPO').AsFloat;
```

Comment: +1 ele não possui nenhum problema com o código dele, o único "problema" ali é permissão de I/O que esta sendo mascarado no `try`